# strtok in nested while loops behaves unexpectedly

Tags: c, strtok

I have a string that looks like 1,3-5,7,9-11 and I'm to tokenize it with repeated calls to strtok so that the output looks something like:

```
1
3
5
7
9
11
```

My code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void tokenize(char *string){
    char *token;
    token = strtok (string,"-");
    while (token != NULL) {
            // ... do some other unrelated stuff ...
            printf("\tToken %s\n", token);
            token = strtok (NULL, ",");
    }
}

int main (int argc,char **argv)
{
    char *token;
    token = strtok (*(argv+1),",");
    while (token != NULL) {
            if (strchr(token,45)){  //45 is ASCII for "-".
                    tokenize(token);
            }
            printf("Token1 %s \n", token);
            token = strtok (NULL, ",");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I run the code it ends prematurely and I get:

```
./tokenizer 1,3-5,7,9-11
Token1 1
        Token 3
        Token 5
Token1 3
```

but I expect/want something like:

```
./tokenizer 1,3-5,7,9-11
Token1 1
        Token 3
        Token 5
Token1 7
        Token 9
        Token 11
```

If I comment out the line that reads `tokenize(temptoken);` (in other words, strtok on "," only), then the output looks like one would expect:

```
./tokenizer 1,3-5,7,9-11
Token1 1
Token1 3-5
Token1 7
Token1 9-11
```

So it looks like the problem really is with the subsequent strtok calls to the already tokenized string so I tried to memcpy memory pointed to be the token pointer but that didn't really help:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void tokenize(char *string){
    char *token;
    token = strtok (string,"-");
    while (token != NULL) {

            printf("\tToken %s\n", token);
            token = strtok (NULL, ",");
    }
}

int main (int argc,char **argv)
{
    char *token;
    char *temptoken ;
    token = strtok (*(argv+1),",");
    while (token != NULL) {
            if (strchr(token,45)){  //45 is ASCII for "-".
/* added memcpy */  memcpy(temptoken,token,strlen(token)+1);
                    tokenize(temptoken);
            }
            printf("Token1 %s \n", token);
            token = strtok (NULL, ",");
    }
    return 0;
} 


$ ./tokenizer 1,3-5,7,9-11 
Token1 1
        Token 3
        Token 5
Token1 3-5
```

Any ideas of what I can do to fix the code, understand where my misunderstanding lies, and get the desired output?

Comment: you `memcpy` **nowhere** ... `temptoken` is an uninitialized pointer. And then, for strings, just use `strcpy` instead (once you properly allocated memory for your target).

Comment: use `strtok_r`, `strtok` has a built-in side-effect.

Comment: Yes, you are correct but I assumed C++ programmers would also be able to answer the question.

Comment: why not strtok ", " - ie on both delimiters

Comment: C++ programmers don't use this stupid `strtok` function.

Comment: @GlenMacLachlan this would just be tag-spam. Although you *could* write such code in C++, you shouldn't. A C++ programmer won't be interested.

Comment: Instead of `45` and a comment, simply use `'-'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not use nested `strtok()` because it uses some static memory to save its context between invocations to know the current position in the string being tokenized.

Use `strtok_r()` instead, which is a reentrant version of strtok that doesn't have any internal state.

Comment: Yes and just reiterating for the OP (and others) that `strtok` is a rather ancient library function-- don't feel bad for being confused by its designed behavior, you're not the first one. Nobody designs library/API functions like this anymore!

Answer (score -1):

```
while (token != NULL) {
        if (strchr(token,45)){  //45 is ASCII for "-".
         /* added memcpy */  memcpy(temptoken,token,strlen(token)+1);
                tokenize(temptoken);
        }
        printf("Token1 %s \n", token);
        token = strtok (NULL, ",");
}
```

And what do you expect.

you are finding the token ','
then tokenize it with your function (and print the tokens)
then you print that token before the subtokenisation again
and it finishes as strtok has an internal state.

So it works exactly as you wrote it.

you need to:
use reentrant version od strtok,

you should return the value in your tokenize function to indicate if subtokens have been found: if not print the token, if yes do not.